# Rank of a block-triagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

Given a matrix $C=\left [ \begin{matrix} A & 0 \\ B & A \end{matrix} \right ]$, where rank(A+B)=rank(B), and rank(B)>rank(A), does rank(C)=rank(A)+rank(B) hold?

A,B are Laplacian matrices.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, it is not homework. It is a formulation that pops up in a proof concerning graph laplacians. It seems to me as if this would hold, but I can't prove it, or at least find a nice counterexample so I can move on.

Answer (score 1):

First, if $A$ is a $M$-matrix then it is invertible and $\mathrm{rank}(B) > \mathrm{rank}(A)$ is impossible.

Here is a counter-example, if
$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
and 
$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ then:

- $B$ is a $M$-matrix;
- $\mathrm{rank}(A+B)=\mathrm{rank}(B)=2$;
- $ 2 = \mathrm{rank}(B) > \mathrm{rank}(A) = 1$;
- $ \mathrm{rank}(C) = \mathrm{rank} 
   \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
    = 2 < \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(B)$.

Comment: Are there multiple definitions of M matrices? They are Laplacian matrices of graphs, and not supposed to have full rank.  However, somewhere it says that Laplacians are M matrices? I am confused.

Comment: Directed graphs that is.

Comment: I did not know before what M-matrices where, so I went to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix). Maybe this is not what you had in mind?